# Determination of open set?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A = {x \in \mathbb R} \ s.t. \  x \neq 0$

I was wondering if this is sound logic to come up with the conclusion that 0 nullifies the notion that A is an open set, because it is a limit point. I know it's open, and is it viable to call 0 a limit point because $x = {(-\infty,0) \cup (0,\infty) }$ and $0$ is a cap from both ends, but by definition of $A$, $0$ is not contained.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Wojowu Sorry! I forgot it. I re-edited the question.

Comment: So? It's *closed* sets that have to contain their limit points, and closed sets are complements of open sets. Seen another way, in $\mathbb{R}$, any one-point set $\{x\}$ is closed, thus its complement is open, e.g. your set.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing notions of open and closed set. Recall the definitions:

> A set $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is *open* if, for every $x\in A$ we have some $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\subseteq A$.
>
> A set $A\subseteq\Bbb R$ is *closed* if every limit point of $A$ is in $A$.

Your set $A$ is, indeed, open, and you can easily prove it by yourself. Your argument shows that $A$ isn't closed, because $0$ is a limit point of $A$, but not an element of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

$A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}: x \neq 0 \} = (-\infty, 0) \cup (0,\infty)$ is indeed open, as the union of two open segments.

The fact that $0$ is a limit point is just because every open interval around $0$ contains points from $A$, which is easy to see. And as $0 \notin A$, $A$ is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Real line is hausdorff, meaning any singleton is closed, which in turn means it's complement is open, ergo $A$ is open.